# Expensive Query on 6 GB table

Tags: sql, postgresql, heroku, rdbms

I have tables Foo and Buzz like so:

```
Foos
buzz_id
date
```

Foo has an index on buzz_id, the foreign key. It also has a index on the date.

```
Buzzes
name
group
```

Buzz has an index on name, an index on group, and a multi column unique index that combines name and group. A Buzz has many Foo.

I am making the following query, and it is taking much too long:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (foos.buzz_id) foos.id, foos.date, buzzes.name, buzzes.group FROM foos INNER JOIN buzzes ON buzzes.id = foos.buzz_id 
WHERE (buzzes.group = ANY (ARRAY_OF_GROUPS) 
AND buzzes.name = ANY (ARRAY_OF_NAMES)
AND foos.date <= GIVEN_DATE) ORDER BY foos.buzz_id DESC, foos.date DESC;
```

I am joining the two tables on the foreign key, and trying to get the highest date of a foo per buzz_id (granted that the buzz's name and group are included in my given arrays and the date condition is satisfied).

I have two environments where I'm running this query, my local machine and a Heroku environment. My local environment has smaller tables as you can see:

```
Local:
 foos                                        | r          |   4.013e+06 | 639 MB
 foos_pkey                                   | i          | 4.19832e+06 | 198 MB
 index_foos_on_buzz_id                       | i          | 4.19832e+06 | 285 MB
 index_foos_on_date                          | i          | 4.19832e+06 | 330 MB
 buzzes                                      | r          |        2298 | 184 kB
 index_buzzes_on_name_and_group              | i          |        2298 | 120 kB
 index_buzzes_on_group                       | i          |        2298 | 104 kB
 index_buzzes_on_name                        | i          |        2298 | 88 kB

Heroku:
 foos                                        | r          | 4.92772e+07 | 6653 MB 
 foos_pkey                                   | i          | 4.90556e+07 | 3151 MB
 index_foos_on_buzz_id                       | i          | 4.90556e+07 | 2462 MB
 index_foos_on_date                          | i          | 4.90556e+07 | 2421 MB
 buzzes                                      | r          |      328250 | 24 MB
 index_buzzes_on_name_and_group              | i          |      328250 | 10200 kB
 index_buzzes_on_group                       | i          |      328250 | 8624 kB
 index_buzzes_on_name                        | i          |      328250 | 7224 kB
```

My local tables are missing data so the query is returning fewer rows than the Heroku environment.

I have a large number of items in the ARRAY_OF_NAMES, 500 in this instance, while relatively fewer items are in the ARRAY_OF_GROUPS, let's say 4.

My Heroku environment does not have the amount of RAM to hold all of my data in cache, so I know that at the moment the speed of the query is slower than if it were all cached.

Running the queries with EXPLAIN ANALYZE gives me the following output:

```
Local:
 Unique  (cost=330087.91..336514.17 rows=1485 width=46) (actual time=3602.511..4131.322 rows=736 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=330087.91..333301.04 rows=1285252 width=46) (actual time=3602.509..4003.598 rows=1404653 loops=1)
         Sort Key: foos.buzz_id DESC, foos.date DESC
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 96096kB
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=311.50..160136.33 rows=1285252 width=46) (actual time=10.815..1438.885 rows=1404653 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (foos.buzz_id = buzz.id)
               ->  Seq Scan on foos  (cost=0.00..131923.55 rows=4013004 width=32) (actual time=1.728..925.871 rows=4186572 loops=1)
                     Filter: (date <= GIVEN_DATE)
               ->  Hash  (cost=301.48..301.48 rows=801 width=18) (actual time=9.035..9.035 rows=736 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 47kB
                     ->  Index Scan using index_buzzes_on_name on buzzes  (cost=0.28..301.48 rows=801 width=18) (actual time=0.057..8.189 rows=736 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: ((name)::text = ANY (ARRAY_OF_NAMES::text[]))
                           Filter: ((group)::text = ANY (ARRAY_OF_GROUPS::text[]))
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 5
 Planning time: 5.804 ms
 Execution time: 4151.021 ms
(16 rows)
```

Heroku:

```
Unique  (cost=1086348.46..1086579.42 rows=17073 width=44) (actual time=64428.256..64980.542 rows=1467 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=1086348.46..1086463.94 rows=230962 width=44) (actual time=64428.254..64801.540 rows=1889788 loops=1)
         Sort Key: foos.buzz_id DESC, foos.date DESC
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 129240kB
         ->  Gather  (cost=3860.54..1082233.34 rows=230962 width=44) (actual time=20.290..61998.689 rows=1889788 loops=1)
               Workers Planned: 1
               Workers Launched: 1
               ->  Hash Join  (cost=2860.54..1058137.14 rows=135860 width=44) (actual time=16.240..61607.831 rows=944894 loops=2)
                     Hash Cond: (foos.buzz_id = buzz.id)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on foos  (cost=0.00..953099.09 rows=28986598 width=32) (actual time=0.312..59310.999 rows=24527783 loops=2)
                           Filter: (date <= GIVEN_DATE)
                     ->  Hash  (cost=2855.15..2855.15 rows=1539 width=16) (actual time=9.022..9.022 rows=1467 loops=2)
                           Buckets: 2048  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 90kB
                           ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on buzzes  (cost=973.85..2855.15 rows=1539 width=16) (actual time=6.534..8.753 rows=1467 loops=2)
                                 Recheck Cond: (((group)::text = ANY (ARRAY_OF_GROUPS::text[])) AND ((name)::text = ANY (ARRAY_OF_NAMES::text[])))
                                 Heap Blocks: exact=902
                                 ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=973.85..973.85 rows=1539 width=0) (actual time=6.416..6.416 rows=0 loops=2)
                                       ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_buzzes_on_group  (cost=0.00..87.51 rows=10174 width=0) (actual time=1.059..1.059 rows=10504 loops=2)
                                             Index Cond: ((group)::text = ANY (ARRAY_OF_GROUPS::text[]))
                                       ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_buzzes_on_name  (cost=0.00..886.14 rows=49668 width=0) (actual time=5.168..5.168 rows=50042 loops=2)
                                             Index Cond: ((name)::text = ANY (ARRAY_OF_NAMES::text[]))
 Planning time: 1.993 ms
 Execution time: 64999.534 ms
```

Do you have any suggestions for speeding up my query or is this expected behavior? I think I must be doing something wrong because I sincerely doubt that I'm pushing postgres to the edge of it performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to get the max date from `foo`, an aggregate query would be more fitting. It will probably be faster as well, worth checking out:

```
select
  b.id,
  b.name,
  b."group",
  max(f.date)
  from buzz b,
       foo f
 where b.id = f.buzz_id
   and b."group" in [ARRAY]
   and b.name in [ARRAY]
  and f.date < NOW()
 group by b.id;
```

Regarding your indices: if this was the only query to be ran on this database, the single-column indices (name and group) wouldn't be helpful as your where condition uses both of them. If there were no other queries joining or filtering based on just one of those columns, you could drop those 2 indices to speed up insert/update.

Comment: re: Susan's answer: moving the where conditions will *not* make this faster. Postgres hash joins onto foo, then scans the date column. The explain plan for my query is identical to the less readable / succinct answer. And my notation for joining buzz, foo is not a cross join. A cross join would occur if I had not specified `b.id=f.buzz_id`. Using `join` or `inner join` produces an identical result, I just prefer the multi-table notation. @Susan

Comment: max(f.date) gives me: ERROR:  column "f.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function. You're correct that moving the where conditions does not make this faster, and it gives me the same query plan.

Comment: Did you add f.id to the list of select? If you need to get the id as well as date, the query needs to be modified a little.

Answer (score 0):

Also move the WHERE conditions to the INNER JOIN. That way your data set is reduced as early as possible. Ideally, you may want to do something like this to reduce the data as soon as possible (and definitely stay away from a cross join):

```
 select b.id, b.name, b."group", max(f.date)
 from (SELECT * FROM buzz bz WHERE bz."group" in [ARRAY] and bz.name in [ARRAY]) b,
   JOIN (SELECT * FROM foo WHERE date < NOW()) f ON b.id = f.buzz_id
 group by b.id;
```